# Rails 4.2 model relationships has_many generated helper methods for objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wondering about the automated helper methods for objects automatically generated by rails.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :steering_wheel, inverse_of: car
   has_many :windows, inverse_of: :car
end

class Window < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car, inverse_of: :windows
end

class SteeringWheel < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car, inverse_of: :steering_wheel
end
```

With this  relationship i can do

```
car = Car.first
car.create_steering_wheel
```

But i would like also to create a new `window`
like

```
car.create_window
```

How is it possible to do this?

Comment: you can do `car.windows.create`

Comment: make that an answer @Vimsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The belong_to association adds this methods

```
association
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```

This means that you can do `window.create_car` if window is an instance of Window

To create an object from the Parent is like this

```
car = Car.first
car.windows.create
```

ref: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Comment: Excellent! thankts for the details and the link, it is not that i haven had this manual open before ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the association builder method

```
car.windows.create
```